# Twilio voice <gather> with fieldtype

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to gather data from the caller like their email address.

In twilio autopilot \collect\ there is a fieldtype TWILIO.EMAIL where it will automatically detect email address in the speech and it really do well (also the other fieldtypes)

But in twilio voice \gather\ there's no fieldtype to do that job and it returns 
johncarlo@gmail.com to john carlo at gmail com

Is there any way in the docs to apply fieldtype in \gather\?
btw, I'm using \gather\ because some questions are dynamic (depends on the answer on the previous question)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I don't think that's possible with `gather` (will double-check though).

> Is there any way in the docs to apply fieldtype in \gather\? btw, I'm using \gather\ because some questions are dynamic (depends on the answer on the previous question)

Autopilot may do the job just fine though. Did you discover the [redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/redirect) property? Using `redirect` you can dynamically route to different tasks depending on an answer. :)

Hope that helps. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I figured that this means I need to prepare all tasks that corresponds to each possible answer on previous questions? that's tedious. I just really hope twilio voice 'gather' has its own fieldtype similar to autopilot 'collect' :(